# disable default behavior of image when try to move in in browser

Tags: jquery

i'm finishing writing a plugin, which allow to zoom images, and then move it, to see other parts of image. But i have a problem.

as we know, when we try to move image, (ie when we `mousedown` on it and move the cursor), the browser don't allow it.

i've written

```
$("img").mousedown(function(e)
{
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

and it works in Mozilla, but doesn't for example in ie.

any ideas?

Thanks much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can sort out IE by also adding `e.preventDefault()` to your document's mousemove event handler:

```
$(document).mousemove(function(e){ 
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: Thanks much man;) but why it only sort out IE? explain please:/

Comment: Because the other browsers are smart enough to recognize the `e.preventDefault()` in your image's mousedown handler.  IE ignores that so you need the extra `e.preventDefault()` call globally on your document.

Comment: Thanks again... (P.s You have very very beautiful children:)

Comment: Hah, it's a survival mechanism for those 3am wake-ups.

Comment: Just an update as I found this late.  I was able to find the solution to this and something similar to it for for touch screens and browsers.  http://www.redips.net/firefox/disable-image-dragging/